# Graylog regex search with numbers in text

Tags: regex, graylog2

I use graylog 2.0 (http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.0/pages/queries.html) and it's super useful.

I want to refine my full_message search. 
Currently I'm:
- searching graylog for all **full_message** occurrences of the start of the string
- I then export this to excel
- Split the text (text to columns)
- Apply an autofilter 
- Filter for any times > 20

search pattern:

```
full_message: "Running queue with*"
```

search text:

```
Network Queue: Running queue with id: dd82c225-fab7-44ce-9618-67d1ef332a03 and 1 items
Network Queue: Running queue with id: dd82c225-fab7-44ce-9618-67d1ef332a03 and 5 items
Network Queue: Running queue with id: dd82c225-fab7-44ce-9618-67d1ef332a03 and 25 items
Network Queue: Running queue with id: dd82c225-fab7-44ce-9618-67d1ef332a03 and 200 items
```

I'm wondering if a better reg search could just list any reccord with items > 20.

e.g. the search string would be

```
full_message: "Running queue with [insert better regex here]"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern

```
Running queue with id: \S+ and (?:\d{3,}|[3-9]\d|2[1-9])
```

The final group there allows for either:

- `\d{3,}` Any number with three or more digits, or
- `[3-9]\d` Any number 30-99, or
- `2[1-9]` Any number 21-29

https://regex101.com/r/ctLvQD/1

Comment: thanks, that's amazing. it looks like the query works as expected in reg101 but doesn't appear to work in graylog. Maybe it's the way that elastic search processes the expression? Does this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax make any sense to you?